# mod-rewrite - sending any URL with ".php/" to 404

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I have a substantial number of rewrite rules in place for a variety of reasons such as:

disallow indexes,
set custom error pages,
force non-www, https,
strip trailing slash,
redirect index.html or.php to root,
pretty URLs (hides file extensions & queries),
404 any URL with Additional Path Info

I was having trouble with nonsense URLs (URLs with Additional Path Info) invoking broken pages & 500 errors that were being indexed as duplicates by search engines. 
Sample: `example.com/index.php/somefolder/another/file/query...`

I set up rules to redirect to a default page rather than rendering broken pages or 500 errors. I then modified that same block to send such nonsense URLs to 404 instead so they would not be indexed.

MrWhite educated me on the proper use of `AcceptPathInfo Off` but unfortunately this had no effect.

The current solution (full array shown below) requires additional .htaccess files inside any sub-directories containing accessible pages but it worked like a charm.

This is the full array of rules currently in place. Everything is now working perfectly. I'm currently working to eliminate the need for the additional htaccess files in the subdirectories.

```
AcceptPathInfo Off    
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## 404 ANY URL WITH ADDITIONAL PATH INFO ##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php/? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,R=404,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]

## SET CUSTOM ERROR PAGES ##
ErrorDocument 400 /error/error_400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error/error_401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error/error_403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error/error_404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/error_500.php

## FORCE HTTPS & NON-WWW ##
## RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dev.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

## STRIP TRAILING SLASH ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

## REDIRECT INDEX TO ROOT ##
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ / [R=301,L]

## PRETTY URLS FOR DYNAMIC FILES ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^items/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ item.php?item=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^items/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ item.php?item=$1 [L]

## PRETTY URL FOR ANY STATIC FILE ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

The block labeled "404 ANY URL WITH ADDITIONAL PATH INFO" would be unnecessary if the "AdditionalPathInfo off" directive would work. This setting can also be controlled in the httpd-conf file on the server. Editing httpd-conf requires command-line, ssh access and can be dangerous. Consult your hosting company or server admin if that sounds scary.

Currently using feedback I've received here to clean this up. Updates to come.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> example.com/index.php/somefolder/anotherfolder/file/query...
> ```

Everything after the file `index.php` in the URL is called "additional pathname information" (or *path-info* for short). Whether this is valid on the URL is, by default, dependent on the file handler - in this case the PHP handler. And the PHP handler allows path-info. This information is available in your script if you wanted to use it, ie. `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`. (By contrast, the text/html handler does not allow path-info, so a request like `/index.html/anything` will - by default - result in a 404.)

If you wish all these "nonsense" URLs to return a 404 then you can simply disable path-info on all requests. For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> ## STRIP ANYTHING AFTER .php/ ##
> ## CREATES CHAIN OF 3 REDIRECTS 302-301-301 NOT GREAT ##
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php/? [NC] 
> RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [NC,R,L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
> ```

It wasn't clear from your [earlier question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128084/htaccess-rewrite-rules-for-nonsense-urls), but you'd put this code in the wrong place - it should go nearer the start of your `.htaccess`, not at the end. It is also conflicting with your other rules, eg. you are appending a slash, but you have an earlier rule that `STRIP TRAILING SLASH` - so this will naturally result in a redirect chain.

You also have code that appends the `.php` extension (via an internal rewrite) immediately above this code block - so this would seem to be unnecessary duplication.

You are also missing some `L` flags on your rules, so processing is going to continue unnecessarily through your file. Whilst it may not strictly be necessary in every case, you can include an `L` flag on each of your `RewriteRule` directives.

However, if you just want to return a 404, then use `AcceptPathInfo Off` instead, as mentioned above.

---

> **UPDATE:** AcceptPathInfo off had no effect. Hosting company can't answer if it's set at the httpd-conf level, can't even provide the correct location for the httpd-conf file. I was able to make it work with rewrite rules.

If you have other mod_rewrite directives (rewrites/redirects) then these can override `AcceptPathInfo`. However, I see nothing in your `.htaccess` file that would do this (except for your more recent "workaround")<sup>***1**</sup>. And the fact that it seemingly "does nothing" is *a bit strange*. Maybe it has something to do with how PHP is handled on your server?

What happens if you request something like:

```
/foo.html/bar/baz
```

...where `/foo.html` is a valid file?

Yes, `AcceptPathInfo` can be set in the server config, however, you should still be able to override this in `.htaccess`. (It would also be a bit silly for a shared host to set `AcceptPathInfo On` in the server config - I assume you're on a shared host?) It is possible that the host has blocked the override of `AcceptPathInfo` in `.htaccess`, however, they should know if they have and this would again be silly if they have. However, on Apache this would result in a 500 Internal Server Error, not a silent fail (unless perhaps you are on a LiteSpeed server?!).

<sup>***1**</sup> **EDIT:** Although you seem to be using multiple `.htaccess` files in subdirectories - any of these could potentially be conflicting. Depending on circumstances, multiple `.htaccess` files is best avoided as it can become a maintenance problem (and confusing to debug).

However, your `.htaccess` file can be simplified....

> The final solution required an additional `.htaccess` file inside the directory containing my custom error pages but it worked like a charm.

You shouldn't need to do that? What did you add?

> The last block (PRETTY URLS FOR ANY STATIC FILE) is also added to a secondary htaccess which is placed in any subdirectories.

Again, you shouldn't need to do that? By default, the mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file will completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent. (So no HTTP to HTTPS redirect, no strip trailing slash, etc.)

> ```
> ## 404 ANY URL WITH ADDITIONAL PATH INFO ##
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php/? [NC] 
> RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,R=404,L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
> ```

This would seem to "block" (404) any URL that simply includes a `.php` extension, rather than URLs that contain path-info. (Your earlier version of this rule stripped the `.php` extension.)

When you specify a `R` code outside of the 3xx range then the *substitution* string (ie. `/%1`) is ignored. (The `L` is alos not required in this case - it is implied.)

As mentioned above, the second rule is superfluous. This has nothing to do with "blocking" URLs that contain path-info. The later rule that states "PRETTY URL FOR ANY STATIC FILE" does the same thing.

To "block" (404) URLs that contain path-info (not just on `.php` files) then you can do the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} .
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

OR, to block only `.php` URLs that contain what "looks-like" trailing path-name information (whether it is really path-info or not, ie. whether the `.php` file exists or not) then you can do this in a single directive:

```
RewriteRule \.php/ - [R=404]
```

> ```
> ## REDIRECT INDEX TO ROOT ##
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ / [R=301,L]
> ```

(What about requests for `.html`?) This can be done in a single directive:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ / [R=301,L]
```

> ```
> ## PRETTY URLS FOR DYNAMIC FILES ##
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^fonts/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ item.php?item=$1 [L]
> RewriteRule ^fonts/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ item.php?item=$1 [L]
> ```

`RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. So, the 2nd rule above is processed unconditionally. Although this is really just one rule - you can make the trailing slash *optional*. However, the preceding rule already "STRIP TRAILING SLASH", so the trailing slash is never present anyway? (Having the trailing slash optional for internal rewrites potentially creates *duplicate content*.)

However, the first condition would seem to be redundant anyway, since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^fonts/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$` is unlikely to match a real file (unless you have physical files that don't have file extensions?!). It could potentially match a directory - but that's your call (do you have subdirectories of the `/fonts` directory? (Is `/fonts` even a real directory?)

So, this could certainly be simplified to (and possibly further):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fonts/([\w-]+)$ item.php?item=$1 [L]
```

The `\w` *shorthand* character class is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

> ```
> ## PRETTY URL FOR ANY STATIC FILE ##
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
> ```

Again, the preceding "file" condition would seem to be unnecessary here (for the same reason as mentioned above). The `QSA` flag is not required, since you've not included a query string in the *substitution* string, so the query string from the request is appended by default.

You mention that you are copying this block to manage extensionless URLs in those subdirectories. That would seem to be unnecessary repetition. You should look into modifying this one rule to cover all necessary subdirectories. Although exactly how you do this could be dependent on your system.

### Summary

Bringing the above points together we get something like the following:

```
AcceptPathInfo Off    
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

## SET CUSTOM ERROR PAGES ##
ErrorDocument 400 /error/error_400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error/error_401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error/error_403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error/error_404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/error_500.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## 404 ANY URL WITH ADDITIONAL PATH INFO ##
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} .
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]

## FORCE HTTPS & NON-WWW ##
## RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule (.*) https://dev.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

## STRIP TRAILING SLASH ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

## REDIRECT INDEX TO ROOT ##
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html?)$ / [R=301,L]

## PRETTY URLS FOR DYNAMIC FILES ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fonts/([\w-]+)$ item.php?item=$1 [L]

## PRETTY URL FOR ANY STATIC FILE ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. I accidentally posted the first question while not logged in so I figured I'd start over. Please see response below.

Comment: Understood on moving it near the top. Definitely conflicting with striping trailing slash.  am I appending the slash in both rules or only the 2nd from this block? I see what you mean with appending the .php in the previous block I may have to live with that but I'll try to remove. Thanks a million for the AcceptPathInfo tip. That should simplify matters. Trying now.

Comment: Could I trouble you to point out where you see missing [L] flags? Now I'm thinking every rule without one needs one. Sounds like this would help isolate the effect of each block.

Comment: "am I appending the slash in both rules or only the 2nd from this block?" - From "this [last] block", just the first rule appends the trailing slash. The 2nd rule is an internal rewrite that appends the `.php` extension (to make it work, because it is stripped by the previous rule). "I may have to live with that" - you should just be able to remove it. I doubt that that last rule is even being processed. "missing [L] flags? ... every rule ... help isolate the effect of each block." - Yes, every rule (whilst it's not strictly necessary in all cases - it is a good idea to "isolate" each block).

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. Please see my edits to the original post. I've updated to the current status. I killed the last block entirely, added the [L] flags, added the AcceptPathInfo off directive and read up on the Apache Docs.

Comment: AcceptPathInfo off had no effect. Hosting company can't answer if it's set at the httpd-conf level, can't even provide the correct location for the httpd-conf file. I was able to make it work with rewrite rules. see edits to original post.

Comment: Curious, `AcceptPathInfo` should have done _something_, unless there is a conflict elsewhere?! I've updated my answer to address this and other simplifications/optimisations with the code in your updated question. I would generally try to avoid additional `.htaccess` files in subdirectories - this should be unnecessary and could potentially be resulting in conflicts. (Note that mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default.)

Comment: Host reports that there is no httpd-conf file by default. I need to create it. Somewhat puzzlingly they said I would need to add the line to enable the "AcceptPathInfo" feature. Would have assumed there would be a default behavior  (on or off). Perhaps with no conf file it defaults to "on" & can't be overridden in .htaccess.  Working to nail that down. The only rule currently included in subdirectories is the "Pretty URLs for Static Files" rule. I do realize that the more local rules will override & could conflict with the more global rules. Looking over your other optimizations now. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed that the presence of the .htaccess files in the subdirectories is not optimal. For example, It does make it possible to reach www & http URLs in those directories unless I add those rules in the subdirectory (like you sad). Also agreed that the 2n'd rule in my workaround is superfluous. I'm on a dedicated server. The support docs were very wrong as to the location of the conf file but a support email cleared up the status as written in my previous comment. Good idea to use a valid html file to test AcceptPathInfo status. Trying now.

Comment: Just for more clarity...The bit about the 2nd rule on ## PRETTY URLS FOR DYNAMIC FILES ## being processed unconditionally is just a result of a flaw in my censoring of the code here. The actual rules apply the conditions to both. To answer your question, "fonts", in this case is not a real directory. It's actually a file that can accept query strings.

Comment: More clarity... The  purpose of the ## PRETTY URLS FOR DYNAMIC FILES ## is basically to allow simple URLs that LOOK like a directory structure (example.com/item/item1) where the actual URL may be example.com/item.php?item=item1

Comment: "they said I would need to add the line to enable the "AcceptPathInfo" feature." - Yeah, not sure what they mean by that either! By default, whether path-info is accepted is dependent on the _handler responsible for the request_. The default Apache handler (ie. the handler that serves `.html` files) does _not_ accept path-info. Which is why I suggested trying `/foo.html/bar`. Setting `AcceptPathInfo On` allows path-info on _all_ file types. Setting `Off` disables path-info on _all_ file types. You don't need access to the server config to set this.

Comment: "I'm on a dedicated server." - So, your server should be pretty much in a "default" config? "...can't be overridden in .htaccess" - it is more likely that a mod_rewrite directive is overriding this. "`fonts`, in this case is not a real directory. It's actually a file that can accept query strings." - `fonts` is a file?! Although your mod-rewrite directive rewrites this to `item.php`? (If `fonts` is not a directory then neither of the conditions are required. (?))

Comment: Sorry for the confusion "fonts" in that case was a lapse in my censorship of the code sample. I've changed it to "items". All that really does is direct /items/item1 to /items.php?item=item1. My reading agrees, with no setting in httpd-conf (no conf file at all) it seems the default behavior for path info should be "on" for php & "off" for html which does appear to be the case. URLs with .html/anything do go 404. Confusing why I can't disable it for php in the htaccess file. I have yet to build a conf file to test if that helps. The tips on shorthand are definitely helpful.

Comment: Working now on a modification of the "Pretty URLs" rules that will cover subdirectories. The secondary htaccess files are a bandaid. I'll update the code in the original question as soon as I have it stable. Thank you!